# Ember Data Beta 2 FixtureAdapter Errors

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm assuming that the API has changed for how to use adapters but I couldn't find any examples using the fixture adapter. I'm using the new injected store but not sure how to interact with it. I'm just trying to fetch all of the data. Here is a fiddle http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ESoduyA/1/edit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/css/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item.type}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('color');
  }
});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
  type: DS.attr()
});

App.Color.FIXTURES = [
  {type: 'blue'},
  {type: 'green'}
];
```

This results in these errors.

```
Assertion failed: No model was found for 'html' ember-1.0.0.js:394
DEPRECATION: Action handlers contained in an `events` object are deprecated in favor of putting them in an `actions` object (error on <Ember.Route:ember245>)
        at Object.triggerEvent (https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:30519:13)
        at trigger (https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:29641:16)
        at handleError (https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:29903:9)
        at invokeCallback (https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8055:19)
        at null.<anonymous> (https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8109:11)
        at EventTarget.trigger (https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:7878:22)
        at https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8180:17
        at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5459:24)
        at Object.Backburner.end (https://rawgithub.com/emberjs/starter-kit/v1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5545:27) ember-1.0.0.js:394
Error while loading route: 
TypeError
 ember-1.0.0.js:394
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some info on the FixtureAdapter.  http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-fixtures/

tl,dr :

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.Color.FIXTURES = [
  {id: 1, type: 'blue'},
  {id: 2, type: 'green'}
];
```

Tweaked bin : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ESoduyA/4/edit